# How can I delete an account from Mozilla history?

Tags: google-account

I'm not using this account anymore. When I go to a Google product website, like BigQuery or Google Photos, it keeps showing me this page. I need it to be gone[image]

I tried to delete cookies and cache, but it will delete all my history

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->privacy then in cookies and site data - clear data.
check cookies and site data.

This will clear all signed in accounts.
this will not clear Web history or bookmarks. but you will have to login again to websites.

You can also try clicking on google signin then forget your account.Select login from another account. Then remove an account. Try this before above solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Multi-Account Containers plugin for Firefox, which can be found at this link: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers. It can really help you as you can switch between containers and each container does not share cookies with other containers.
For example, you can have one container with a logged-in account and a second container without a connected account.

[image]

Alternatively, you can simply use new private windows to achieve similar results.
[image]